# NSNotificationCenter not firing when application is terminated and launched again in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, appdelegate, nsnotificationcenter

I have a logistics app which has a requirement to disable the screen recording, and I don't want people to use the new iOS-11 feature to record the screen with sensitive datas and make them public. Since disabling screen recording is not possible in iOS so i tried a work around by detecting the iOS11 screen recording feature On or Off. I used isCaptured and UIScreenCapturedDidChange Notification. The code is given below:

```
   - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(screenCaptureChanged) name:UIScreenCapturedDidChangeNotification object:nil];
    }

    return YES;
 }
```

So the logic is when the screen recording starts the notification is fired and the logic of placing the black color on video while recording is happening and when the recording stops the black color is removed. This works fine when the application is moved to background , active , inactive and foreground scenarios. But when the application is killed(terminated) while screen recording is still going on and when we launch the application again while screen recording is still going on the black color doesn't covers the screen. So how to call the notification selector again with the selector method working

Comment: Try UIscreen.main.iscaptured flag in didfinishwithlaunchoptions method

Comment: can you help me with a sample app and share it with me? please :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the value of the screen's `isCaptured` property in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` and show or hide the overlay view accordingly.

UIWindow+ScreenCapture.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface UIWindow (ScreenCapture)

- (void)showOrHideContentDependingOnCapturedState;
- (void)hideContent;
- (void)showContent;

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

UIWindow+ScreenCapture.m:

```
#import "UIWindow+ScreenCapture.h"

@implementation UIWindow (ScreenCapture)

- (void)showOrHideContentDependingOnCapturedState {
    if (self.screen.isCaptured) {
        [self hideContent];
    } else {
        [self showContent];
    }
}

- (void)hideContent {
    UIView *blackView = [self viewWithTag:1234];
    if (!blackView) {
        blackView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds];
    }

    blackView.tag = 1234;
    blackView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor;
    blackView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

    // This is important! If this is not set, then any new view added to
    // the window (like the root view controller's view) will be overtop of
    // `blackView`, which we don't want.
    blackView.layer.zPosition = 10000;

    [self addSubview:blackView];
}

- (void)showContent {
    [[self viewWithTag:1234] removeFromSuperview];
}

@end
```

AppDelegate.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (nullable, strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@end
```

AppDelegate.m:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "UIWindow+ScreenCapture.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(checkIsBeingRecorded)
                                                 name:UIScreenCapturedDidChangeNotification
                                               object:nil];
    [self.window showOrHideContentDependingOnCapturedState];

    return YES;
}

- (void)checkIsBeingRecorded {
    for (UIWindow *window in UIApplication.sharedApplication.windows) {
        [window showOrHideContentDependingOnCapturedState];
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: thanks for the response i tried the same but it is not working... Can you please try a sample application and confirm? if possible please... Thanks a lot for reply :)

Comment: Yeah, I made a sample app and it's working for me. Maybe something else is wrong? Maybe your app delegate's `window` property is nil? Try putting breakpoints all around to see where the problem lies.

Comment: Sure .... Can you please host it in a github and share it with me for reference? it would be a great help for me :)

Comment: Hope you are there Tyler :)

Comment: @FionaShoff Hi, sorry, I had assumed you weren't using scenes, so when I went to make an example app using the iOS 13 SDK I ran into some issues that had to be resolved. I'm pretty sure those are the same issues you're running into, so check out my updated answer to see if that helps!

Comment: Thanks Tyler for this kind help .... I will surely check and let you know 

Comment: hey Tyler can you please post the SceneDelegate.h code too? I wish to know the base class of it .. Currenlty it is @interface SceneDelegate : UIViewController

Comment: It's just the same thing you get when you make a new project in Xcode 11 using the "Single View App" template. You should already have a SceneDelegate in your app, but if not then I've updated my answer with SceneDelegate.h. Also you might have to configure your app to adopt scenes, so take a look at [Apple's documentation on that here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/app_and_environment/scenes) and the WWDC 2019 videos on the topic [like this one](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/258/) and [this one](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/246/).

Comment: Thanks a lot so if i am not wrong we need to have XCode 11 for getting SceneDelegate ? Currently i have Xcode 10.3

Comment: Ahhh okay, in that case my entire answer is incorrect. (And yes to answer your question - you need Xcode 11 to use the iOS 13 SDK.) I had assumed your `AppDelegate`'s `window` property was nil, and that this was caused by you adopting scenes in your app, but now that I know that's not the case then I'll update my answer again. I think I know what the problem was originally (see my note above where I change `blackView.layer.zPosition` to `10000`, making it show up in front of any newly-added views).

Comment: Hey Taylor... Sorry to mention that i wasn't using Scenes . I developed my application in Xcode 10.3 which has 2 view controllers.. So as said if i start recording while app is active or i move to background or inactive state the recording is overlaid with black color. But if i kill the application and again launch it while the screenrecording is still on then initially the black color comes for few seconds but soon the splash screen and view controllers become visible. This only happens when i kill the application and launch again while screen recording is in process

Comment: Hey Taylor if i am correct i just need to add "blackView.layer.zPosition =10000" to my original posted code of "if(isCaptured)" loop ?

Comment: Yeah, try that out!